# Makefile is not creating a directory

Tags: c, unix, makefile

Teacher gave us this makefile for compiling two C files and storing the objects into a directory called object. It compiles the programs fine however it doesn't store their objects into the directory, and it also doesn't even create the directory. Not sure what to do and could really use some help.

This is my make file

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

OBJDIR = object
HDRS = $(wildcard *.h)
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS:.c=.o))

.PHONY: all
all: client server 

# WARNING: must have a tab before each definition

$(OBJDIR)/client.o: client.c $(HDRS) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c client.c -o object/client.o

$(OBJDIR)/server .o: server.c $(HDRS) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c server.c -o object/server.o  

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(HDRS) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $*.c -o object/$*.o

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
```

Comment: Tangential to your problem, the compiling lines that contain `object` should use `$(OBJDIR)` instead.

Comment: Your makefile doesn't have a rule to build either `client` or `server` so it uses it's built-in default rules instead.

Comment: There probably shouldn't be a space between 'server' and '.o' on the `$(OBJDIR)/server` line.

Comment: Regarding: `mkdir $(OBJDIR)`  This can fail for a bunch of different reasons.  Should be checking for its' success/fail status/.   Since you state the sub directory is NOT created, it obviously failed. At a minimum use the` `-v` option and the `--mode= value` options

Comment: regarding the macros, like: `OBJDIR = object`   Using a the `=` results in the macro being re-evaluated every time it is referenced.  Suggest using: `:=` so they are only evaluated once

Comment: @user3629249 If `mkdir` fails, it should return a non-zero value, and make will report this.

Comment: @thebusybee,  but the user only will see that `make` failed, not that the call to `mkdir` failed.  And to have control over the accessibility of the files in the `object` directory, use the `--mode=` parameter and to have `mkdir` tell you why it failed, use the `-v` parameter.

Comment: regarding expressions like: `object/client.o` Strongly suggest using `$@`

Comment: Why does the user not see the call of `mkdir`? Make commonly prints all commands before executing them. And `mkdir` prints error messages.

Comment: @user3629249 With the makefile as shown, I don't think the `$(OBJDIR)` rule will even get run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was add multiple targets to the makefile and change all to target the targets

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -g -Wall 

# TODO: rename the target to something meaningful!
TARGET = client server

OBJDIR = object
HDRS = $(wildcard *.h)
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS:.c=.o))

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)

# WARNING: *must* have a tab before each definition
$(TARGET): $(OBJDIR) $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/protocol.o $(OBJDIR)/$@.o  -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(HDRS) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $*.c -o object/$*.o

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
```